# 503 response in Laravel since Composer update

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

Since I did my last Composer update, I always get an `503(Service Unavailable)` when I do a `dd()`, `die` or `exit`. Are there any known issues? Google couldn't bring the answer.

I'm using Laravel 5.1,
my last Composer package was [`barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you tried composer dump-autoload -o ?

Comment: Sadly, that didn't the trick. But thank you for you answer.

Comment: Does it only happen when you dd()? Everything else works?

Comment: No, it also happens when i do a exit or die. Otherwise all work well

Comment: Hmm I was going to suggest to try artisan up but you said everything else works... Sorry not sure what it would cause that.

Comment: I already tried artisan up. No effect

Comment: Try to remove the `vendor` folder and run `composer install`. If this doesn't work, get your working backup and run `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`. Never do a `composer update` when you only want to install a new package. Always use `composer require …` instead.

Comment: Thank you, @Peh! Now dd() ist working again. Sadly, dompdf isn't insallable. Always when i try it, i run into the dame "dd()" issue. Now i'll try barryvdh/laravel-snappy. Thank you all.